# Split message in serial communication

Tags: c#, serial-port, packets

I am new to serial communication. I have read a fair few tutorials, and most of what I am trying to do is working, however I have a question regarding serial communication with C#. I have a micro controller that is constantly sending data through a serial line. The data ist in this format:
bxxxxixx.xx,xx.xx*
where the x's represent different numbers, + or - signs.
At certain times want to read this information from my C# program on my PC. The problem that I am having is that my messages seem to be split in random positions even though I am using 
ReadTo("*");
I assumed this would read everything upto the * character.
How can I make sure that the message I recieved is complete?

Thank you for your help.

```
    public string receiveCommandHC()
    {

        string messageHC = "";
        if (serialHC.IsOpen)
        {
            serialHC.DiscardInBuffer();
            messageHC = serialHC.ReadTo("*");

        }
        return messageHC;
    }
```

Comment: when you say that it got split in odd positions, can you be more specific?

Comment: its being split into random messages, meaning that sometimes messageHC will be bxxxi and then the next time it returns something like xx or whatever.

Comment: Delete the DiscardInBuffer() call, it does nothing but cause undiagnosable loss of data.

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you for the comment, I have deleted it and it does help, however, as described in some of my comments below I am still not consistantly getting complete messages returned. I think i need to recompose all the information i get into a complete message and then return this from my function, I am however not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll nearly always find in serial comms that data messages (unless very small) are split. This is mostly down to the speed of communication and the point at which you retrieve data from the port.

Usually you'd set your code to run in a separate thread (to help prevent impacting the performance of the rest of your code) which raises an event when a complete message is received and also takes full messages in for transmission. Read and write functionality is dealt with by worker threads (serial comms traffic is slow).

You'll need a read and a write buffer. These should be suitabley large to hold data for several cycles.

Append data read from the input to the end of your read buffer. Have the read buffer read on cyclicly for complete messages, from the start of the buffer.

Depending on the protocol used there is usually a data start and maybe a data end  indicator and somewhere a message size (this may be fixed, again depending on your protocol). I gather form your protocol that the message start character is `'b'` and the message end character is `'*'`. Discard all data preceeding your message start character ('b'), as this is from an incomplete message.

When a complete message is found, strip it from the front of the buffer and raise an event to indicate its arrival.

A similar process is run for sending data, except that you may need to split the message, hence data to be sent is appended to the end of the buffer and data being sent is read from the start.

I hope that this helps you in understanding how to cope with serial comms.

As pointed out by Marc you're currently clearing your buffer in a way that will cause problems.

**edit**

As I said in my comment I don't recognise serialHC, but if dealing with raw data then look at using the `SerialPort` class. More information on how to use it and an example (which roughly uses the process that I described above) can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.aspx).

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. The b was meant to be part of the message, I think from what I understand is that i should send a clear "start of message" command and an "end of message" command and then find what was sent between these. Once ive got the complete message I can then return that from my function.

Is there a simple way of doing this?

Comment: @ChrisBD this would certainly be true if using raw reads, however I *believe* that `ReadTo` does the buffering internally, with a read-loop.

Comment: Marc, would you suggest I use raw reads? I still dont quite understand how I can piece together the data I AM recieving into a complete message. I can change the data being sent by my micro controller to include specific start of message and end of message commands if that helps.
Sorry for the simple questions, very new to this as a mechanical engineer.

Comment: @Marc - Yes I was dealing with raw data input. I'll admit that I didn't recognise serialHC.

Comment: @user1173059 before I try to answer that, does removing the `Discard...` fix it?

Comment: @MarcGravell it definately seems to help, but i am still not consistently getting complete messages to return from my function

Comment: @ChrisBD Hey, thank you for your help, serialHC is of the SerialPort class:
`SerialPort serialHC = new SerialPort(); // serial connection dealing with Hand Controller`
I just call it serialHC because I am also using a serial line to to communicate with a robot, this serial is communicating with a custum built hand controller.

Comment: @MarcGravell and ChrisBD, thank you for your help and patience with me. I managed to figure something out :)

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure why you're doing it, but you're discarding everything in the serial ports in-buffer just before reading, so if the computer has already received "bxxx" at that point, you throw it away and you'll only be reading "xixx.xx,xx.xx".

Comment: wow, that was pretty simple, i think that did the trick. Just wondering though, wont my buffer overflow??

Comment: @user1173059 er, no. The `Discard...` call drops data that has already arrived, but which you have not yet consumed.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to take a guess that you're actually getting the **ends** of commands, i.e. instead of getting `b01234.56.78.9` (omitting the final `*`), you're getting (say) `.56.78.9`. That is because you **discarded the input buffer**. Don't do that. You can't know the state at that point (just before a read), so discarding the buffer is simply wrong. Remove the `serialHC.DiscardInBuffer();` line.